# Equivalence norm between two fundamental descompotition (krein spaces).

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inner-products, spectral-theory

Im working on a corolary in this article: http://www.people.virginia.edu/~jlr5m/Papers/p46.pdf  corolary 2, page 5.

I understand the argument shown, more precisely how to prove that

$$
f'_+=Xf_++(I-Y)f_-,
$$

$$
f'_-=(I-X)f_++Yf_-
$$

But im stuck getting a costant $m$ to show that $m|| f ||_{|\mathfrak{H}|} \le || f ||_{|\mathfrak{H}|'}$, i know those relations will make it but i dont really know how to approach. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem at the top of page 5 shows that $X$ and $Y$ are bounded. Then 
\begin{align}
\|f\|_{|\mathfrak H|'}^2&=\|f_+'\|_{|\mathfrak H|'}^2+\|f_-'\|_{|\mathfrak H|'}^2\\ \ \\
&=\|Xf_++(I-Y)f_-\|_{|\mathfrak H|'}^2+\|(I-X)f_++Yf_-\|_{|\mathfrak H|'}^2\\ \ \\
&\leq (\|X\|\,\|f_+\|_{|\mathfrak H|}+\|I-Y\|\,\|f_-\|_{|\mathfrak H|})^2
+(\|I-X\|\,\|f_+\|_{|\mathfrak H|}+\|Y\|\,\|f_-\|_{|\mathfrak H|})^2\\ \ \\
&\leq M(\|f_+\|_{|\mathfrak H|}^2+\|f_-\|_{|\mathfrak H|}^2)\\ \ \\
&=M\,\|f\|_{|\mathfrak H|}^2,
\end{align}
where $M$ is obtained by collecting terms after expanding the squares and using the easy inequality $|2ab|\leq a^2+b^2$).

The other inequality is obtained in the same way after solving your two equation linear system in terms of $f_+$ and $f_-$.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.